Request sequence listed in the patent US20210290676A1
I wonder if you could provide me with the sequence (ID NO. 253-255 and 316-318). Thank you very much, and look forward your reply.

The cited document is an application, not yet a patent. You can look it up on the USPTO PatentCenter and click the supplemental content link for the sequence file.
